# Assertion types "as" in template Vue 3 not working in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How do I configure WebStorm + TypeScript so that it understands the type assertion in the Vue 3 template?

VSCode:

[image]

JetBrains WebStorm:

[image]

WebStorm settings:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

WebStorm doesn't currently support using Typescript syntax in template expressions. Please vote for [WEB-55049](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55049/TypeScript-syntax-as-type-cast-keyword-in-Vue-3-template) to be notified on any progress with it. It's currently planned for version 2023.1